# JQuery problems with .each() and creating a decision tree

Tags: jquery

I am having problems with my code. It should take an object containing 4 strings and using a function it should create 4 rectangles which the user can click on. Once the user clicks on a rectangle I am applying some animation to it before it disappears. I then want to return the exact one that was clicked and then repeat this with a new function.

Apologies if that is confusing, I have a JFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rickdonohoe/dpPj7/ which should show it.

My problems are:

1. It haven't been able to change the html content based on the object of strings passed into the function.
2. I'm not sure how to return the one which was clicked.
3. In the each() function each div is created with a class of four_q1. I want this to increment for all 4 with four_q2 etc How do I do this?

Oh and this is my first JFiddle so any problems or criticism please let me know!

Thank You,

Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I messed with it, stripped some junk out, and got this... it should start you in the right direction.

Remember, you can't parse an object for each element in a standard format, try an array instead.
Also, it's a bad idea to pass jQuery objects around. Instead try passing the selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/dpPj7/20/

//===== After Comments ======

http://jsfiddle.net/dpPj7/33/

Comment: Cheers for the fiddling. I done my own little take on that. The only part you had missed was in the for loop 'i' was wrong so it only outputted 3 rather than 4 values. Still, if I had enough reputation that would be a definite vote up!!

Comment: Oh s**z.. lol, yeah I see that now. I was just doing a quick looksie anyways. But Cheers, and I'm glad it got you where you needed to go! (And I get the points for you accepting it as the answer, so no worries)

Comment: Quick question if you don't mind, How would I get the whole thing to repeat? As in once the click animations have finished, add call the function again with a different array list?

Comment: @RickDonohoe okay now we're getting into 'why' but I'll make some assumptions. First of all you need an event of some kind to trigger the function call then. In which case you could make it event specific and anonymous. I guess I'm going to have to ask you to give me a step through of what the flow would be for the end user? This way I can guide you toward the events, and order of operations you need. =D

Comment: These 4 clickable areas are questions which lead to more questions. If you check out the fiddle it has 2 array lists. The function takes the 2 arguments (one been the array) and should return which answer was clicked. It should then call the function again with a new array, but this shouldnt happen till the first animations are finished....

Comment: can I ask why you're setting those object variables then never using them? I took them out, and you put them back in, but still don't use them. Oh and you shouldn't define a variable in the arguments section of a for loop.

Comment: I set selected as a variable as I planned to return it at the end of the function as a reference to which of the four areas were clicked. I'm not sure about the lists method, ideally I only want to accept 1 array because if the function correctly returned which one was clicked, then I could do a MySQL call to receive ANOTHER array from a database RELATED to the answer that was chosen previously. See what I mean? Trailed your recent answers and gave you a few votes up too bud ;)

Comment: I see what you mean... How about you put together a wire, of the information transfer and you e-mail it to me: http://jsfiddle.net/dpPj7/34/

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `$.each(question_list, fn)` instead of `$(question_list).each(fn)`;
2. You have two options: assign `on("click")` to your divs inside that each function, just after you created them, so it will be a closure on the element you want; or you can save the object in your element using `data`;
3. The argument for [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is a function that receives the index/property key in the array/object, and the corresponding element. You could use that to determine the class.

Full example:

```
$.each(question_list, function(key, element) {
    $('<div class="four_q1">' + element + '</div>')
        .addClass("four_q" + key)
        .on("click", function() {
            // element is accessible here
        })
        .appendTo(container);
    current++;
}
```